# Rider cannot resolve symbols related to Xamarin.iOS framework

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, rider, jetbrains-rider

JetBrains Rider states that it cannot resolve quite a lot of symbols including `UITableViewCell`, `ContentView`, `bool`, `decimal`, `string`, `void` and many more.

[image: Rider IDE]

In the solution explorer, Rider indicates a warning sign for all the *Assemblies*.

[image: assemblies]

Below are my build settings,

[image: build settings]

`.csproj` of the iOS project contains,

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
...
```

I've tried restoring NuGet packages and restarting Rider after *Invalidating Caches*.

I'm using the latest stable version of Rider `2022.2.4` and I've even tried the latest EAP version `2022.3 EAP 9` but nothing seems to work. However, the project runs/debugs without an issue in both physical devices and iOS simulators in Rider. Visual Studio `17.4` doesn't show these errors and works fine. Running on MacOS `12.6.1` if that's relevant.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the csproj for that project look like?

Comment: @Cheesebaron `csproj` is huge. Which specific part of it do you want to see?

Comment: Do you have an ItemGroup in there with ` <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />`?

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes I can see it under `<ItemGroup>` tag.

Comment: `git clean -ffdx` and restore NuGet packages again. If that doesn't help ‍♂️

Comment: @Cheesebaron `git clean -ffdx` + restoring NuGet packages didn't help as well . I've reported this in [Rider Support Forum](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8811847314706-Rider-cannot-resolve-symbol-UITableViewCell-Xamarin-iOS) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Feb 08, 2024:** Issue once again appeared in Rider version `2023.3.3`. Now even restarting the IDE does not work.

---

**Update Oct 23, 2023:** This has not been an issue for me since the Rider version `2023.2.2`. It seems that the issue is fixed now.

---

**Update Mar 09, 2023:** At this point my solution to this problem is just restarting Rider until it gets fixed. I know this is not a stable solution but it works with 2-3 restart attempts. Just close Rider, open it again and wait for the project to sync.

---

**Update Feb 10, 2023:** Found the previous solution to be unreliable. It doesn't always work. The issue appeared again after updating the MacOS to 13.2; I hardly believe it's related to the MacOS update.

---

So the issue was that NuGet packages were not getting restored properly in Rider. The solution was to restore NuGet packages using Visual Studio.

- Open Visual Studio
- Switch to the iOS solution and choose the correct configuration (Debug/Release) and platform (Device/Simulator)
- Right-click on the project name in the *Solution* panel
- Click *Restore NuGet Packages*

Wait until the restoration completes, switch to Rider, and wait for it to synchronise project files if it still has the issue try restarting Rider.